# Having problems with Microsoft teams new webhook

Tags: microsoft-teams

I  had a webhook i was using from my ansible playbook to send notification to  one of our  Microsoft teams channel.The webhook URL was like this

"https://outlook.office.com/webhook/*".I got a notification on teams that i need to update to a new version on the webhook which is  now this " [https://organization-name.webhook.office.com/webhookb/*"](https://organization-name.webhook.office.com/webhookb/*%22) .After i updated to the new webhook  and tested on my ansible play book, i got  the following error

"msg": "Failed to validate the SSL certificate for organization-namer.webhook.office.com:443. Make sure your managed systems have a valid CA certificate installed. If the website serving the url uses SNI you need python >= 2.7.9 on your managed machine  (the python executable used (/usr/bin/python) is version: 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:42:36) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)]) or you can install the `urllib3`, `pyOpenSSL`, `ndg-httpsclient`, and `pyasn1` python modules to perform SNI verification in python >= 2.6. You can use validate_certs=False if you do not need to confirm the servers identity but this is unsafe and not recommended. Paths checked for this platform: /etc/ssl/certs, /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem, /etc/pki/tls/certs, /usr/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org, /etc/ansible. The exception msg was: hostname 'organization-name.webhook.office.com' doesn't match either of '*.internal.outlook.com', '*.outlook.com', 'outlook.com', 'office365.com', '*.office365.com', '*.outlook.office365.com', '*.office.com', 'outlook.office.com', 'substrate.office.com', 'attachment.outlook.live.net', 'attachment.outlook.office.net', 'attachment.outlook.officeppe.net', 'attachments.office.net', '*.clo.footprintdns.com', '*.nrb.footprintdns.com', 'ccs.login.microsoftonline.com', 'ccs-sdf.login.microsoftonline.com', 'substrate-sdf.office.com', 'attachments-sdf.office.net', '*.live.com', 'mail.services.live.com', 'hotmail.com', '*.hotmail.com'."}

From the error , it shows that Microsoft have not added the *.webhook.com  domain to the  domains names defined in the SSL certificate.

My question, how do i go about this?..any input will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it has to do with python version. Upgraded my python version to 2.7.5 and i was good to go. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Byg Eynst, great to know that it works...
However just for your information,  Each Webhook has an expiration date at which time it can no longer be used just like Cerftificate. This expiration date can be modified after the Webhook is created.

 

For more information, see the details of a webhook section of this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks#details-of-a-webhook

Comment: Hello @Saonti-MSFT, When I'm trying to connect to the webhook URL  https://organization-name.webhook.office.com/webhookb/*"   I'm getting unable to find valid certification path to requested target;
nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Could you please assist me in how can I download the certificate for the webhook url?